# Передать выбранный объект в контроллер через функцию в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, select

Здравствуйте Друзья!
Возникла следующая ситуация необходимо из select во вьюшке передать выбранный объект в контроллер через функцию объявленную в параметре ng-change.
Вьюшка:

```
 <select name="region" id="region_of_birth" class="form-control"
         ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in regionsList"
         ng-model="model.BornRegionId"
         ng-change="refreshBornDistricts(item)">
     <option></option>
 </select>
```

Контроллер:

```
$scope.refreshBornDistricts = function (item) {
    console.log(item);
};
```

Comment: а что не так с приведенным кодом?

Answer (score 0):

Можно пойти другим путем. ng-model будет хранить весь выбранный объект и в refreshBornDistricts ничего передавать не нужно.

Вьюшка:

```
<div ng-controller='myController'>
  <select name="region" id="region_of_birth" class="form-control"
     ng-options="item as item.Name for item in regionsList"
     ng-model="model.BornRegion"
     ng-change="refreshBornDistricts()">
     <option></option>
 </select>
 {{ model.BornRegion }}
</div>
```

Контроллер:

```
$scope.refreshBornDistricts = function () {
   console.log($scope.model.BornRegion);
};
```